# Parsing out file - specific issue

Tags: python

I have been given a student problem as I am learning python in school. I am struggling a bit to think of ways to solve it. This is an example of the file that I have to parse out:

```
cupboard_blue “a”   drawer1       -1 
cupboard_blue “a”   drawer2       -1
cupboard_blue “a”   drawer3       -1 
cupboard_blue “a”   drawer4       -1  
cupboard_blue “b”   drawer1       -1  
cupboard_blue “b”   drawer2       apple 
cupboard_blue “b”   drawer3       -1  
cupboard_blue “b”   drawer4       -1  

cupboard_yellow “a” drawer1       -1 
cupboard_yellow “a” drawer2       -1
cupboard_yellow “a” drawer3       -1 
cupboard_yellow “b” drawer1       -1 
cupboard_yellow “b” drawer2       lychee  
cupboard_yellow “b” drawer3       -1 

cupboard_red  “a”   drawer1       pear 
cupboard_red  “a”   drawer2       pear 
cupboard_red  “b”   drawer1       pear 
cupboard_red  “b”   drawer2       pear
```

There are different colour categories of cupboards - in the example above there are red, yellow, and blue cupboards. Each colour has two different cupboards ‘a’ and ‘b’ - i.e. 2 blue cupboards and 2 red cupboards in total. 
Each cupboard has drawers that may be empty or full of fruit.

I want to write a script where I parse out only the colour types where all cupboards in that category have all drawers that are full of fruit. So in the example above the output would be:

```
cupboard_red  “a”   drawer1       pear 
cupboard_red  “a”   drawer2       pear 
cupboard_red  “b”   drawer1       pear 
cupboard_red  “b”   drawer2       pear
```

I would really appreciate some guidance on this problem. I hope it makes sense.

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! please read up on
[how to ask a question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking) and provide a
[minimal, complete and verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)
that reproduces your problem.

Comment: I agree with @hiroprotagonist, the key word being minimal. The code could be accurately reproduced in a few lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to find which lines have a certain string in them, and I also assume you need to open the file then this code can put you on the right track

```
output = []
word = "pear"
with open("file.txt") as file:
    lines = file.readlines()
    for line in lines:
        if word in line:
            output.append(line)

print(output)
```

Comment: Thank you for this Darkchilli. However, I know how to find a line with a certain string in them. The issue is with specific problem: put simply, I need to parse out the cupboard colours in which all drawers contain fruit. I do not want to print out cupboards where only one of the drawers has fruit in them. Perhaps I should delete this post and re-write? Sorry for the inconvenience.

Comment: No, its fine. All you need to do instead is take the first cupboard, for loop through it checking if everything has a fruit in it, if so append it to a list and carry on. If not, carry on. You could also split it every blank line.

Comment: Okay, cheers! So if I loop through all drawers, and only if all drawers of a particular colour contain fruit I append this to a list. Am I right in thinking that I should use a union function?  where only one drawer has fruit then it will not make a union,